# How to reconnect a URLSessionWebSocketTask once its cancelled?

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, ios13, urlsessionwebsockettask

I am cancelling or disconnecting an active WebSocket task using the following code

```
socket.cancel(with: .goingAway, reason: nil)
```

Is there any way to reconnect back or should we create a new URLSessionWebSocketTask and resume again ?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new URLSessionWebSocketTask and resume again.